# plot factor frequency by group (a yield plot)

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a data frame containing the test_outcome (PASS/FAIL) for each test_type performed on each test_subject. For example:

```
test_subject, test_type, test_outcome 
person_a, height, PASS
person_b, height, PASS
person_c, height, FAIL
person_d, height, PASS
person_a, weight, FAIL
person_b, weight, FAIL
person_c, weight, PASS
person_d, weight, PASS
```

I would like to prepare a yield plot by test_type and test_subject.

```
Y-axis = yield i.e. num pass/(num pass + num fail)
X-axis = test_subject
fill: = A line for each test_type.
```

I would prefer to use ggplot2, can you please recommend the best approach here? e.g. how to reshape the data before plotting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick dplyr answer, you will want to tidy up the graph based on your desired colours etc.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- dat %>% group_by(test_subject, test_type) %>%
               summarise(passrate = sum(test_outcome=="PASS") / n())

ggplot(dat, aes(x = test_subject, y = passrate, fill = test_type)) +
       geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Edit: a line graph was requested. Normally, categorical groups shouldn't be connected by a line graph - as there is no reason to order them in a particular way.

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = test_subject, y = passrate,  col = test_type)) + 
       geom_line(aes(group = test_type)) +
       geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you. is z the dat data frame? I guess the same method can be used for geom_line()

Comment: Thank you. Hum, i'm getting "Error in n() : This function should not be called directly"

Comment: do you have plyr and dplyr both loaded? Try running detach(plyr), or change summarise to dplyr::summarise

Comment: yes, that was the problem (both plyr and dplyr were loaded). detach(plyr) worked a treat. Thank you!